# Gibbs' Free Energie

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

What terms are needed to consider to create a rabbit out of nothing and place it in the classroom?

[image: La foto]

Does this caption answer the question?

Comment: *"to create a rabbit out of nothing"* -  nihil fit ex nihilo

Comment: Nothing is made out of nothing... yeah, the beauty of Romance languages, double-negatives.

Comment: Okay this is an excerpt from Daniel V Schroeder's _Thermal Physics_. It's an hilarious analogy which states that you don't have to supply the whole enthalpy $H$ as there would be an additional energy associated with the change in entropy due to the _creation_ of rabbit in constant temperature and pressure. This whole thing constitutes the Gibbs energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This picture explains better for creating a rabbit. The picture you showed is good for understanding Gibbs energy, but not good for describing creation of a rabbit. [image]